# How to run a function after all test cases BOOST c++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I have a problem, I am pondering; if there are any macros, features in C++ BOOST library, that will run a function once after **ALL** test cases.

I want to run a function which will be creating a json file with no. of executed tests, no. of passed test and no. of all tests. So i have that problem, because i **MUST** work with file that is build in specific way:

f1()
f2()
f3()
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(f1){}
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(f2){}
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(f3){}

So I cannot create main() function which would do that for me, because im getting an error that there is a previous declaration in /boost/test/unit_test.hpp.

Thank you in advance. Greetings.

Comment: You're looking for [fixtures](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/fixtures.html) -- probably a [global fixture](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/fixtures/global.html)

Comment: Or, if you want to actually create a `main()`, there is a way to [redefine the entry point](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/adv_scenarios/entry_point_overview.html)

Comment: @DanMašek that was it, thanks! I tested that, and this is what i was looking for!

Comment: Ok, I'll write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least two possible approaches to this problem.

The first would be to use a [fixture](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/fixtures.html), or more specifically a [global fixture](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/fixtures/global.html).

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE example
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

struct Fixture {
  Fixture()   { /* Run on startup */ }
  ~Fixture()  { /* Run on tear down */ }
};

BOOST_GLOBAL_FIXTURE(Fixture);

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_case)
// ... and so on
```

The other option would be to use the functionality provided in the library for [overriding the entry point](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/adv_scenarios/entry_point_overview.html), so that you can use your own `main()` as you attempted.

Answer (score 0):

OT: This may be off-topic as the question explicitly mentioned the BOOST library.

My personal experience is that there are unit-testing frameworks for C++ that are actually more suitable for the C++ language (taking advantage of the C++ language itself; not blindly copying the old unit-testing framework design), easier to configure (just copying one file with the full implementation; no external dependencies), and easier to use.

Have a look at the [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch) unit-testing framework. It also supports nicely the Test-Driven Development, and the Behavior-Driven Development.

(For example, the [nanodbc](http://lexicalunit.github.io/nanodbc/) project recently switched from the BOOST to Catch after some evaluation. The existing tests can be rewritten almost mechanically -- replacements via editor tools.)